# AngularJS ng-model on select input doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel

I'm starting with AngularJS and tried to do a  and get its value with Angular, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="app_container" ng-controller="ArticlesController as control">
<select name="sortby" id="sortby" ng-model="sortBy"> {{sortBy}}
    <option name="Date" value="Date">Date</option>
    <option name="Vues" value="Vues">Vues</option>
    <option name="Note" value="Note">Note</option>
    <option name="Catégorie" value="Catégorie">Catégorie</option>
    <option name="Tags" value="Tags">Tags</option>
</select>
<div>
```

Here I want to display the value of the select input, but it displays nothing. I can't access this value from the controller neither, and I don't understand why.
I have a ng-repeat on the same page that works perfectly well.
I even tried to copy past the example from angularjs.org, even this doesn't work...

Comment: You have to use ng-repeat or ng-options for that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using controller as syntax, you need to use **`ng-model="controlsortBy"`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('ArticlesController',function(){
   var control = this;
   control.print = function(){
     console.log(control.sortBy);
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div id="app_container" ng-controller="ArticlesController as control">
<select name="sortby" id="sortby" ng-change="control.print()" ng-model="control.sortBy">
    <option name="Date" value="Date">Date</option>
    <option name="Vues" value="Vues">Vues</option>
    <option name="Note" value="Note">Note</option>
    <option name="Catégorie" value="Catégorie">Catégorie</option>
    <option name="Tags" value="Tags">Tags</option>
</select>
<h1> {{control.sortBy}}</h1>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I do have the right result in the console. This is a progress. But {{sortBy}} doesn't work still

Comment: agian you need to use {{control.sortBy}}